# OpenCV 4.5 counterpart of OpenCV 2.4 cvCreateImageHeader method

Tags: opencv

I'm upgrading a codebase from **OpenCV v2.4** to **OpenCV v4.5** and I'm looking for the **cvCreateImageHeader** method counterpart.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no counterpart to [that function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/df8/group__core__c.html#ga950feef7abcbd6c19c83543f25849ee2).

It's roughly equivalent to the [constructor of a `cv::Mat`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a75a97b1e4e55f380c172af58048a7cde), except such a constructor also allocates memory. other constructors of `cv::Mat` can use existing memory.

The "new" API (since OpenCV v2.x) combines depth and channels into one code, e.g. CV_8UC3 stands for 8U values (uint8), 3 channels.

```cpp
cv::Mat foo { cv::Size(width, height), CV_8UC3 }; // contemporary C++
```

If you need more detail, you need to post code.

Comment: I never touched the v1 C API so this was a bit of archaeology (and guessing!) for me.